# Is it possible to remove Blender Render/Internal render?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, customization

I want to clean up a bit in my Blender UI, and thus want to completely remove Blender Render.

Is this possible? And will it have any negative effects in working with cycles (create bugs/similar)?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? The only difference to the UI when in cycles mode would be a little drop down at the top. If you want it to load cycles by default, change it to cycles, then save the .blend preferences

Comment: I optimize everything, according to a principle called Kaizen. If I don't need it, it's better to remove it. And if there is only one render engine, I don't need the drop down menu at all (less cluttered UI) =)

Comment: When it comes to loading cycles by default, I'm not able to do it properly. I have done it in the startup .blend. But if I create a new scene, it opens with Blender Internal by default.

Comment: You changed to Cycles and pressed `Ctrl`+`U` then clicked the message? It should work.

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise Yeah. And I do get cycles on startup, but if I create a new scene, the new scene is in Blender Render.

Comment: That is most certainly as bug. You may need to re-install Blender.

Comment: what you should optimize is the interface for a better workflow, it worked to me quite well to remove the things I do not use and create my own combinations of tools in #D view, since some functions do not use them much or I have never used them so I only charge some add-ons and I've removed some others that it brings by default

Comment: @Einar ask here we develop 2.79c for lovers blender 2.7.xxx [Palestine Discore](https://discord.gg/SJSZHyf)

Answer (score 2):

I have searched in many places information about blender render and if I can deactivate as when you deactivate cycles or renderman21, but as far as I understand, it is not possible since its name indicates it is the internal render, and a basic and fundamental part of blender

[image: Engines]

Comment: all those are render engines?

Comment: its usefulness is infinite, despised by the fans of cycles, I realize this because I like it and I use it but when I try to learn new things about rendering, almost nobody knows how to use the internal blender nodes

Answer (score 1):

Cycles can be removed as an addon, but Blender Internal is...internal.

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: blender internal is hard coded as a fundamental part of blender, cycles was added as an optional renderer 3-4 years ago.

Comment: Are you sure about this? Do you have any sources for this statement?

Comment: @Einar they explained it to you in the previous answer to this one in much more detail, and where you can confirm this is in blender developer talk, You can also consult branch 2.7 and read the source code and its documentation